# HTML nested table layout

Tags: html, html-table

Here is a simple question about HTML layout. The code below illustrates it.
In each cell of the top table there is a sub-table. I would like each sub-table to take the whole space inside the cell(of the top table) it is using. But this is not what is happening. In fact each sub-table is only using the space it needs to display its own contents. How can I modify the code to get the result I want?

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>
        <table bgcolor=#334433>
            <tr><td>
                Al
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <table bgcolor=#334433>
            <tr><td>
                Peter Wells
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <table bgcolor=#334433>
            <tr><td>
                World Champions in the 20th century
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the width:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>
        <table bgcolor=#334433 style="width:100%">
            <tr><td>
                Al
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <table bgcolor=#334433 style="width:100%">
            <tr><td>
                Peter Wells
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <table bgcolor=#334433 style="width:100%">
            <tr><td>
                World Champions in the 20th century
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried. It works. Thanks. .... I need to wait 7 minutes to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.tbl{
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>
        <table class="tbl" bgcolor=#334433 >
            <tr><td>
                Al
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <table class="tbl" bgcolor=#334433>
            <tr><td>
                Peter Wells
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <table class="tbl" bgcolor=#334433>
            <tr><td>
                World Champions in the 20th century
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Here is the code :